# Dynamic macro-selection in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, c-preprocessor

I have a header file 'a.h' with some macro-definitions of the type:

Header 'a.h' contents:

```
#define STREAM1 cout
#define STREAM2 cerr
#define STREAM3 some_out_stream3
#define STREAM4 some_out_stream4
...
#define STREAM100 some_out_stream100
```

Now in a different c file which includes the above header, I need to use the above macros, in the following way.

```
STREAM1 << some_text_method( 1 );
STREAM2 << some_text_method( 2 );
...
STREAM100 << some_text_method( 100 );
```

Is there a way, possibly by macro or function definition, to do the above in a loop:

```
int i;
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    SOME_MACRO_OR_METHOD( i );
```

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, they can't depend on run-time variables.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of streams?

Comment: I know you're asking about C but you could take a look at how Boost.Preprocessor does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the macros in an array and loop over them.

```
std::ostream streams[] = {STREAM1, STREAM2, ...STREAM100};

for (int i = 0; i < std::size(streams); i++) {
    streams[i] << some_text_method(i+1);
}
```